# Android RecyclerView drawing issues (flicker)

Tags: android, refresh, android-recyclerview

I have Activity1 with a fragment which has a RecyclerView in it.
Selecting an item on the list starts Activity2 which modifies the item.
Returning back to Activity1 after Activity2 finishes I observe that the RecyclerView first draws the pre-Activity2 state (saved old item state), then in onActivityResult I do restartLoader() which delivers an updated set of data and then RecyclerView redraws itself again with the new data.

The problem with this behavior is that the RecyclerView *flickers* because it originally draws old data then redraws itself with the new data. Assuming I always want to use refreshLoader() in Activity1.onActivityResult(), is there a good way to avoid such flickering?

---

Additional complication is that I use empty view to show when recycleview is empty... This adds to flickering even more...

Comment: is there any ways you can just update data of singleitem rather than whole by using notifyItemchanged(getAdapterPosition());?

Comment: It is possible that items also get deleted or added to list by other activities. Technically, reload everyone from DB seems to be more universal approach than tracking single item.

Comment: Sorry couldnt get what you meant ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove update flickering on recycler view you can use:

```
 RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator();
    if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
        ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
    }
```

To update an items in RecyclerView you should use

```
    notifyItemChanged(int position)
```

- Notify any registered observers that the item at position has changed.

instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @Califf but this doesn't seem to work with adding items, i am using load more to push more items in the list which flickers but when i delete them no flickering issue...